# How can I grab all the child elements in XML?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

From this XML response: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/xml.php?showuser=335389

I want to grab all of the users friends. I need to grab all of the information from the friends. Usually with the help I've been given I would use the unique ID to grab each, but since each users doesn't have the same friends it has to be dynamic and I can't hard code anything.

Would anyone please share some XDocument magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all `<user>` elements in the `<friends>` element from the XML document like this:

```
var url = "http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/xml.php?showuser=335389";
var doc = XDocument.Load(url);
var friends = doc.Element("ipb").Element("profile")
                 .Element("friends").Elements("user");

// Or if you don't want to specify the whole path and you know that
// there is only a single element named <friends>:
var friends = doc.Descendant("friends").Elements("user");
```

Then you can use LINQ to process the collection. For example, to create a `IEnumerable<string>` with the names of all frineds, you could write:

```
var names = from fr in friends 
            select fr.Element("name").Value;
```

If you needed unique ID, you could read the `<id>` element in a similar way (if it is an integer, you could also parse it using `Int32.Parse` for example...)

Answer (score 0):

you can probably use XPath query

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp

the examples uses JScript but it is also supported in .NET